# Get real time update for durable functions activties

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a long running task built with durable functions. To make it intuitive to the user I'd like to be able to report back the real time status/progress.

As an example, the first activity returns a list of items. For each item, a new activity is called. Essentially the items are handled in parallel.

Is there a way to let the user know the status of each item's activity?

```py
items = yield context.call_activity('do_thing', None) #eg. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

batch_task = [context.call_activity('do_another_thing', item) for item in items]
results = yield context.task_all(batch_task)
```

Is there a way to report back to the user when they query the orchestration that task N of 5 have been completed?

I currently use custom statuses to report back the stages, but I'd like to get more granular if possible.

```py
context.set_custom_status = {"stage": "fetching items"} 
items = yield context.call_activity('do_thing', None) #eg. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

context.set_custom_status = {"stage": "creating batch tasks"} 
batch_task = [context.call_activity('do_another_thing', item) for item in items]
results = yield context.task_all(batch_task)
context.set_custom_status = {"stage": "complete"}
```

Comment: You can await on each task of `batch_task` collection and later can wait for all taks to complete using `task_all`. I'm not so familiar with python but you can [this](https://hamidmosalla.com/2018/04/27/using-task-whenany-and-task-whenall#gist89258698) as reference which is written in C#.

Comment: @user1672994 Cool I think you're on to something, I don't understand C#, but heading in the right direction.

Comment: @user1672994 correct me if I'm wrong. So instead of `task_all` the person instead individually calls the tasks and reports it back. I'm just wondering if this then turns my flow synchronous?

Comment: All tasks are already started asynchronously. when like `batch_task = [context.call_activity('do_another_thing', item) for item in items]` is executed. So in `.Select` it just reporting when individual are completed and via `.WhenAll` to proceed further in execution when all tasks are completed.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll just need to find how that translates to Python. Thanks much appreciated.

Comment: @Ari , Did you get any solution on that if yes then please post answer? , It will be help for community.